# $2 \times 3 = 5+1$ and $2+3 = 5 \times 1$. When else can we switch the operators like this?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I noticed the following:
$$2 \times 3 = 5+1$$
If you switch the operators, it is still true:
$$2+3 = 5 \times 1$$
There is another obvious/trivial example where you can swap the operators:
$$2\times 2 = 2+2$$
I think these are the only solutions (for positive integers). Can anyone give an elegant proof?

Answer (score 5):

Your claim is correct. Indeed, suppose that $ab = c+d$ and $a+b = cd$.
It is clear that at most one of the values $a,b,c,d$ can be equal to $1$, so w.l.o.g. we may assume that $a$ and $b$ are both at least $2$.

We have $$ab = c + \frac{a+b}{c} \leq (a+b)+1,$$
and dividing by $b$ gives
$$a \leq \frac{a}{b} + 1 + \frac{1}{b} < \frac{a}{2} +2,$$
from which we get $a < 4$; hence $a=2$ or $a=3$.
Similarly, $b=2$ or $b=3$.
The four remaining possibilities for $(a,b)$ can now be checked one by one.

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question: why is your first inequality true?

Comment: Ramiro, you're right, this inequality is false. The LHS is at least c, which can be chosen arbitrarily large, in particular greater than (a+b)+1.

Comment: @Ramiro: for integers $c,d \geq 2$, $cd \geq c+d$.

Comment: @ZackWolske: I still don't see it.

Comment: @Visitor: You can't choose c greater than (a+b)+1, because you are constrained by the fact that $a+b = cd$, which in particular implies that $c \leq a+b$.

Comment: @Ramiro: Notice that the function $f(c) = c + \frac{a+b}{c}$ is a convex function of $c$. Thus, to maximize it on the interval $1 \leq c \leq a+b$ (the left inequality follows from us wanting $c$ to be a positive integer, the right inequality follows from the fact that $a+b = cd$) it suffices to plug in the endpoints of that interval. Well, $f(1) = f(a+b) = (a+b) + 1$, so $f(c) \leq (a+b) + 1$ on that whole interval.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: Thanks!